# Operação de soma em Python

Tags: python

Alguém pode me explicar como faz a soma de dois números inteiros entre os mesmos, ou seja do primeiro número até o segundo número (que não está incluso)?

Aqui está um exemplo:

```
numero1 = int (input("Digite o primeiro numero: "))
numero2 = int (input("Digite o segundo numero: "))

Entrada:
N1 = 1
N2 = 3

Saida = 3
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara. Poderia [edit] e dar exemplos do que precisa?

Comment: `print(a + b)`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu editei.

Comment: E por que a saída é 3 para a entrada 1 e 3? Seria a soma 1+2? E se a entrada for 1 e 7, qual deverá ser a saída?

Comment: Os valores de entrada e saída e a descrição foram tiradas do run.codes onde meu professor passa as questões, e as vezes ele coloca algumas informações erradas nas questões

Comment: @SonoGoku Não estão necessariamente erradas, mas são insuficientes para entender a questão. Edite a pergunta e transcreva o enunciado completo do exercício.

Comment: Espera aí! O que isso esta se tornando? Um simples "faz e me entrega" ?

Comment: `resultado = list(range(numero1,numero2))
print (sum(resultado))` esse era o cálculo que fazia o que eu queria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numero1 = int (input("Digite o primeiro numero: "))

numero2 = int (input("Digite o segundo numero: "))

resultado = 0

resultado = list(range(numero1,numero2))

print (sum(resultado))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(range(inicio, final + 1))
```

só.

Comment: `resultado = list(range(numero1,numero2))
print (sum(resultado))` esse era o cálculo que fazia o que eu queria

Answer (score 2):

Cara, sua pergunta não ficou nada clara, mas me corrija se entendi errado.

Você quer fazer um somatório. Somar desde o valor n1 até o valor n2.

Exemplo: `n1 = 1` e `n2 = 5`. O resultado será 10, pois 1+2+3+4 = 10.

Isso foi o que deu a entender.

**Lógica**

Você declara uma variável contadora que tem início no `n1` e faz ela ser incrementada até que chegue no limite, que é `n2`.

**Solução em Python**

Obs.: Você faz com o laço que preferir, escolhi o `while` porque era mais rápido.

```
n1 = int(input("Digite o valor de n1: "))
n2 = int(input("Digite o valor de n2: "))

soma = 0

i = n1

while i < n2: //Para somar o n2 também, é só colocar <=
    soma = soma + i
    i = i + 1

print("O valor da soma é = ", soma)
```

É isto. Avisa se for isso mesmo.

Comment: Se for realmente isso, a [resposta do jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/374912/5878) já faz de uma forma bem melhor.

Comment: ,Mas essa é um pouco mais didática

Comment: Testei aqui, realmente faz a mesma coisa kkkk é bom que ele entende o que ta acontecendo por trás daquela única linha.

Comment: As informações foram tiradas do run.codes, sinceramente acho que alguns valores que o professor cria pra fazer as questões estão erradas

Comment: @SonoGoku faça como foi dito no outro comentário, posta a pergunta exata que ta no run.codes. Provavelmente a resposta do jsbueno ou a minha, resolverão o problema.

Comment: `resultado = list(range(numero1,numero2))
print (sum(resultado))` esse era o cálculo que fazia o que eu queria

Comment: Bom, essa resposta tu já tinha https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/374912/129017

E tu ainda fez um trabalho a mais de colocar numa lista kkk

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seria isso?

```
numero1 = int (input("Digite o primeiro numero: ")) # 1
numero2 = int (input("Digite o segundo numero: "))  # 3

nrSaida = len ( range(numero1 ,numero2) ) + 1

print(nrSaida) # 3
```

Comment: `len ( range(numero1 ,numero2) ) + 1` é apenas uma forma mais complicada de escrever `numero2-numero1+1`.

Comment: No run.codes apenas 5/10 casos são executados corretamente enquanto que os outros 5/10 dão resultados incorretos

Comment: A verdade é que o cara não sabe nem o que ele quer, e a gente aqui discutindo pra adivinhar só pra ganhar uns pontinhos na comunidade. #ProntoFalei. =P

Comment: `resultado = list(range(numero1,numero2))
print (sum(resultado))` esse era o cálculo que fazia o que eu queria